# How to overcome MemoryError from numpy.unique

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, array

I am using Numpy in version 1.11.1 and have to deal with an two-dimensional array of

`my_arr.shape = (25000, 25000)`

All values are integer, and I need a unique list of the arrays values. When using `lst = np.unique(my_arr)` I am getting:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#38>", line 1, in <module>
    palette = np.unique(arr)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\arraysetops.py", line 176, in unique
    ar = np.asanyarray(ar).flatten()
MemoryError`

My machine has only 8 GB RAM, but I tried it with another machine with 16 GB RAM, and the result is the same. Monitoring the memory and CPU usage doesn't show that the problems are related to RAM or CPU.